# Bag nHibernate com key null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

Olá,

Alguém sabe se é possível utilizar Bag do nHibernate com o Key Null?

Em uma tabela alguns registros possui varios registros relacionados, um para muitos, mas nem sempre, as vezes um regitro nao tera nehum.

Fiz o mapeamento por uma bag mas da erro de foreign key por que o campo na tabela relacionada as vezes estará nulo.

Existe alguma forma de trazer uma coleção de registro dessa forma que preciso.

Segue o código das classes e mapeamentos:

Classe que possui os registros pais:

```
public class Fatura
{
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime DtEmissao { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal VlrTotal { get; set; }
    public virtual Convenio Convenio { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Receber> Receber { get; set; }

    public Fatura()
    {
        Receber = new List<Receber>();
    }

}
```

Classe que possui os registros filhos:

```
public class Receber
{
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Fatura Fatura { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime Pagamento { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal Valor { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal Juros { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal Multa { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal OutrosAcrescimos { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal Desconto { get; set; }
}
```

Mapeamento da classe pai:

```
public class FaturaMapping : ClassMapping<Fatura>
{
    public FaturaMapping()
    {
        Table("FATURA");

        Id(x => x.Id, x =>
        {
            x.Column("ID_FATURA");
        });

        Property(x => x.DtEmissao, x =>
        {
            x.Column("DTEMISSAO");
        });

        Property(x => x.VlrTotal, x =>
        {
            x.Column("VLRTOTAL");
        });

        ManyToOne(x => x.Convenio, x =>
        {
            x.Column("FK_CONVENIO");
            x.NotNullable(true);
        });

        Bag(x => x.Receber, x =>
        {
            x.Key(y =>
            {
                y.Column("FK_FATURA");
                y.NotNullable(false);
            });
        }, x => x.OneToMany());

    }
}
```

Comment: Edmar, poderia  editar sua pergunta e colocar para nós seu código de mapeamento?

Comment: Olá Felipe, editado. Obrigado.